# Create dictionary by index in from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, dictionary

[image: example of my data]

My data is 200 columns of IDs, with values for 10 years.  I am only interested in the monthly values, so I assigned the month column as the dataframe index and dropped the date column.  I want to create a dictionary where the ID is the key, and within each ID there are 12 months with the first non-zero value for each month.  something like this     [ID][MONTH] = value

Here's what I have so far.  I'm having trouble looping through the dataframe and assigning the values by index to a dictionary.

```
 IDdict=dict()


    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    df.drop(['DATE'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df = df.set_index(['Month'])

   IDs =[]
    IDs = list(df.columns)

    for ID in IDs:
        IDdict[ID]=dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

months = list of all month

```
for ID in IDs:
    IDdict = dict()
    for month in months:
        IDdict[month] = df[(df["Month"]==month)&(df[ID]!=0)].index[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using numeric values for the index rather than the month names. This way the pivot table will be easier to sort on the index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ('1/1/2014', 1, -950, -5954, 0, 0, -64430),
        ('1/1/2015', 1, 0, -5084, 0, 0, -29896),
        ('2/1/1995', 2, -5160, -1403, 0, 0, -16281),
        ('2/1/1996', 2, 0, -1573, 0, -14, -30772),
    ],
    columns=['Date', 'Month', 'ID_1', 'ID_2', 'ID_3', 'ID_4', 'ID_5']
)
#        Date  Month  ID_1  ID_2  ID_3  ID_4   ID_5
# 0  1/1/2014      1  -950 -5954     0     0 -64430
# 1  1/1/2015      1     0 -5084     0     0 -29896
# 2  2/1/1995      2 -5160 -1403     0     0 -16281
# 3  2/1/1996      2     0 -1573     0   -14 -30772
```

Convert data to a long format using [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['Date', 'Month'], var_name='ID')
#        Date  Month    ID  value
# 0  1/1/2014      1  ID_1   -950
# 1  1/1/2015      1  ID_1      0
# 2  2/1/1995      2  ID_1  -5160
# 3  2/1/1996      2  ID_1      0
# 4  1/1/2014      1  ID_2  -5954
```

Drop all zero values

```
df = df[df.value != 0]
#        Date  Month    ID  value
# 0  1/1/2014      1  ID_1   -950
# 2  2/1/1995      2  ID_1  -5160
# 4  1/1/2014      1  ID_2  -5954
# 5  1/1/2015      1  ID_2  -5084
# 6  2/1/1995      2  ID_2  -1403
```

Group by Month and ID and take the first row

```
df = df.groupby(['Month', 'ID']).first().reset_index()
#    Month    ID      Date  value
# 0      1  ID_1  1/1/2014   -950
# 1      1  ID_2  1/1/2014  -5954
# 2      1  ID_5  1/1/2014 -64430
# 3      2  ID_1  2/1/1995  -5160
# 4      2  ID_2  2/1/1995  -1403
# 5      2  ID_4  2/1/1996    -14
# 6      2  ID_5  2/1/1995 -16281
```

Pivot the table back to a wide format where each column is a month using [`df.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='Month', columns='ID', values='value')
# ID       ID_1    ID_2  ID_4     ID_5
# Month
# 1      -950.0 -5954.0   NaN -64430.0
# 2     -5160.0 -1403.0 -14.0 -16281.0
```

Convert dataframe to a dict using [`df.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

```
df.to_dict('list')
# {'ID_1': [-950.0, -5160.0], 'ID_2': [-5954.0, -1403.0], 'ID_4': [nan, -14.0], 'ID_5': [-64430.0, -16281.0]}
```